# Fineuploader: Getting the uuid up to the server

Tags: uniqueidentifier, fine-uploader

How do you utilize the uuid on the upload?  All I've read is about sending it back with the response.

I'm using v4.1 with the UI jquery wrapper setup.
Could I just add an additional param into my endpoint?  Is there an easy way, or do I create a new uuid in my 'submitted' logic?  Does that submitted event fire before getting sent up to the server?  See?  I'm confused!  Thanks for your help!

Here's my code:

```
// Uploader control setup
    var fineuploader = $('#files-upload').fineUploader({            
        debug: true,
        button: $("#button"),
        request:
        {
            endpoint: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Survey")',
            customHeaders: { Accept: 'application/json' },
            params: {
                surveyInstanceId: (function () { return instance; }),
                surveyItemResultId: (function () { return surveyItemResultId; }),
                itemId: (function () { return itemId; }),
                loopingIndex: (function () { return loopingCounter++; })
            }             
        },
        validation: {
            acceptFiles: ['image/*', 'application/xls', 'application/pdf', 'text/csv', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'],
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp', 'csv', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'xlt', 'xltx', 'txt'],
            sizeLimit: 1024 * 1024 * 2.5, // 2.5MB
            stopOnFirstInvalidFile: false
        },  
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom'
        },
        multiple: true,
        text: {             
            uploadButton: 'Select your upload file(s)'
        }   
    }).on('submitted', function(event, id, filename) {          
        $("#modal-overlay").fadeIn();
        $("#modal-box").fadeIn();
        filesToUpload++;
        $(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');         
    }).on('complete', function (event, id, filename, responseJSON) {
        uploadedFileCounter++;
        if (filesToUpload == uploadedFileCounter)
        {                
            $(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]').removeAttr('disabled');                                                
            //$("#overlay").fadeOut();
            $("#modal-box").fadeOut();
            $("#modal-overlay").fadeOut();               
        }                           
    }).on('error', function (event, id, name, errorReason, xhr) {
        //$("#overlay").fadeOut();
        alert('error: ' + errorReason);
        $("#modal-box").fadeOut();
        $("#modal-overlay").fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Are you trying to send the UUID with the request? If so, it should be sent by default.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to send this value to the server to create a unique upload file name.  Problem is, when I looked to the upload endpoint method and examined the objects being passed in I wasn't able to see anything that resembled a unique value.  Can I get a hint as to where I can find this? :)  Or am I going about this wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I guess you'll have to look at the request closer.  A UUID is always sent with each request .  It's a form field, just like all other parameters in the request.  The default name of this parameter is qquuid.

Comment: Also, the `submitted` event is **always** called before the upload occurs, and immediately after the `submit` event in the case that it does not return a `false` value. [More from the events documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood when Ray mentioned the REQUEST.  I was simply looking at the HttpPostedFileWrapper object that's the file upload container.  It wasn't there.  As he said, look at the REQUEST object, and grab the value like this (probably many other ways too):

```
var id = HttpContext.Request["qquuid"];
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note: the request, by default, will contain a UUID via the `qquuid` key, but you can configure that using the [`request` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request-option_1).